# Universal Analytics Track Events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need help with tracking events with Google Analytics.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-16728174-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Code being used to track the event in Behavior > Events > Top Events

```
<a href="www.sjgweb.com.au" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'banner application', 'form submitted',   'apply now active');"> Apply Now </a>
```

At this stage there is no data in the events, please advise

Comment: have to wait like 24 hours before you will see anything

Comment: I am wanting to add this into an HTML email to track the clicks on the apply now banner. Is this still the same if you add it into an email.

Comment: .... i'm fairly certain you can't embed javascript into an email. that would be so easy to exploit.

Comment: Do you know how to enable javascript within the email?

Comment: you are misunderstanding. No sane company would ever allow users to execute whatever javascript they want. People go to great lengths to embed malicious javascript into an email to do illegal things. Please give up on your quest to embed javascript in an email.

Comment: Oh... great thanks for that didn't realise.

Comment: If you are wanting to track clicks on a link or something in an email, then you can use manual campaign tagging: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en. Just create the campaign tags, and use the resulting URL in the email.

Comment: No data in Analytics Today Please help